If I have a Playwright locator (using sync API and Python), can I determine the HTML element type it is of?
I'm using Sync API and Python for Playwright testing, and I have a python variable that is my locator, already found. I need to know what type of HTML element this locator is, because I need to do some extra coding for certain types of elements.
Say I did this in code:
my_locator = self.page.get_by_role('some_valid_role')
Now I want to know if my_locator is a DIV element or a Span element? How can I do this?

When you find something on a webpage with Playwright, you can check what type of HTML element it is (like a <div>, <span>, or <button>).
To do this, you ask Playwright to "tell" you the element’s type, and it will respond with the name of the element (like "DIV", "SPAN", etc.).
So, you can figure out if it's a box, text, or button based on that response.
